# Transfer 150GB of files from an old MacBook Pro with Ubuntu 13.04 Live DVD

Tags: ubuntu, networking, files, nfs, macintosh

My girlfriend's old MacBook Pro 2009 (5,4) stopped working. I have tried several times to reinstall OS X, but could not do so. There appears to be something really really wrong with the OS.

Since she is not opposed to the idea of using Ubuntu instead of OS X, I am currently trying to transfer all of her files to my Linux machine using an ethernet crossover cable.

Since OS X does not work at all, I am using the Ubuntu 13.04 live DVD to access her files.

At first I thought the job would be simple. My plan was to set up network interfaces, plug in the crossover cable, set up an NFS share on the Macintosh HD, and `rsync` all 150GB of her files over to my machine. Then install Ubuntu 13.04 as the sole operating system, and transfer the files back over.

But, alas, things are not that simple. NFS doesn't seem to like Apple's HFS+ filesystem. At least, I can not get it to work. I also can not find information about how to configure it. Since all of that takes time, I'm wondering if there's a simpler, better solution.

I thought of using an `rsync` daemon, but since both computers are running Ubuntu (the client is using 12.10), and since I can mount the HFS+ hard drive in order to browse through her files, and since both computers can `ping` each other, it just seemed like there would be an easier way to do this than trying to configure NFS.

Comment: Why not just rsync via SSH or native rsync?  No need for NFS.

Comment: How about removing the drive from her Mac, plugging it into the Linux machine, mounting it, and copying the files natively?

Comment: the linux machine is an asus netbook, stabledog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use `scp`. This requires you to install the ssh server on your 12.10 with `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` if you have not already done so. Make sure both machines have a fixed IP address and that they can ping each other if you use a cross-over cable.

Then under 13.04 you mount the HFS+ file-system e.g. under /mnt/hfs. After that

```
cd /mnt/hfs
scp -rp . username@ipaddres:/dir/to/backup
```

The `username` has to be an existing user on the 12.04 machine, with a password. `ipaddress` should be the IP address of the 12.04 machine. `/dir/to/backup` should be on a file-system on 12.04 that has enough free space.

The ssh server does not need further configuration after installation, much less hassle than trying to get NFS to work. And no extra installs after booting from the 13.04 DVD.

Comment: How would that be different from using rsync (which is what the topic starter suggested in his last paragraph)?